# Работа со строкой. split()

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Исходные данные:**

```
q = "На данный продукт распространяются условия ограниченной гарантии Apple, предоставляющей право на соответствующее обслуживание и ремонт аппаратного обеспечения.Предполагаемая дата окончания срока действия: 23 сентября 2019 г.Ознакомьтесь с информацией Apple относительно права на сервисное обслуживаниедля вашего продукта ссылка откроется в новом окне"
```

**После q.split()**

```
q = ['На данный продукт распространяются условия ограниченной гарантии Apple, предоставляющей право на соответствующее обслуживание и ремонт аппаратного обеспечения.\nПредполагаемая дата окончания срока ', ' 23 сентября 2019 г.\nОзнакомьтесь с информацией Apple относительно права на сервисное обслуживание для вашего продукта\nссылка откроется в новом окне']
```

**Вопрос-задача:**

Почему разбивает на список по строчно? Потому что при записи в переменную передались и "\n"? 
Задача "вырезать" дату (здесь как пример, а так дата всегда разная). 
**Нуждаюсь в совете.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Задача "вырезать" дату

Вы имеете в виду **"извлечь"**?

Наверное вы можете разбить исходную строку по подстроке `действия:`, далее выбрать второй элемент списка (тот, что с датой), разбить его по слову `Ознакомьтесь` и выбрать первый элемент из получившегося списка. На примере исходных данных:

```
In [18]: q = "На данный продукт распространяются условия ограниченной гарантии Apple, предоставляющей право на соответствующее обслуживание и ремонт ап
    ...: паратного обеспечения.Предполагаемая дата окончания срока действия: 23 сентября 2019 г.Ознакомьтесь с информацией Apple относительно права на 
    ...: сервисное обслуживаниедля вашего продукта ссылка откроется в новом окне"                                                                      

In [19]: q.split('действия: ')[1].split('Ознакомьтесь')[0]                                                                                             
Out[19]: '23 сентября 2019 г.'
```

Или сделать это с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
In [20]: import re                                                                                                                                     

In [21]: re.findall('\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4} г.', q)                                                                                                         
Out[21]: ['23 сентября 2019 г.']
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, не удалось повторить ваш пример: `split()` разбил всю строку нормально.

Однако для удаления даты я бы предложил использовать регулярное выражение

```
q = re.sub(r"\d.*[.]", "", q)
```

Оно удалит подстроку `23 сентября 2019 г.`, а для удаления `Предполагаемая дата окончания срока действия: 23 сентября 2019 г.` можно использовать

```
q = re.sub(r"[П].*[.]", "", q)
```